# Componente desde un JSON en React CoreUI

Tags: html, json, reactjs

Hola y muchas gracias desde ya.
Me encuentro trabajando con React y CoreUI. Haciendo unas tablas para un formulario de pedido de productos de una empresa.

En CoreUI hay un archivo UsersData.js que es desde donde saca todos los datos para renderizar las tablas. Modificando ese archivo logré crear distintas columnas y cambiar nombres de algunas cosas. (ese archivo tiene datos de ejemplo, más adelante en el proyecto obtendré esos datos desde el backend).

Mi duda es la siguiente. En una de las columnas tiene que mostrarse un "select"(HTML) para que el cliente pueda especificar la cantidad de productos que quiere comprar. Ese "select" tiene que salir desde ese JSON porque desde ahí se obtiene toda la info para renderizar la tabla. No puede venir desde otro lado (o al menos no se me ocurrió la solución todavía).

Aquí está el JSON. En la columna "subtotal" me gustaría que se renderice el "select".

```javascript
export const fields = ["nombre", "precio", "cantidad", "subtotal"];


export const usersData = [
  {
    nombre: "Maltas",
    id: 0,
    productos: [
      {
        id: 0,
        nombre: "Hola prueba",
        precio: "2018/01/01",
        cantidad: "Guest",
        subtotal: "", //En éste key debería ir el componente
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        nombre: "Samppa Nori",
        precio: "2018/01/01",
        cantidad: "Member",
        subtotal: "", //Aquí también, (y en todos los keys "subtotal")
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        nombre: "Estavan Lykos",
        precio: "2018/02/01",
        cantidad: "Staff",
        subtotal: "",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        nombre: "Chetan Mohamed",
        precio: "2018/02/01",
        cantidad: "Admin",
        subtotal: "",
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        nombre: "Derick Maximinus",
        precio: "2018/03/01",
        cantidad: "Member",
        subtotal: "",
      },
    ],
  },
```

Probé creando el componente en ese archivo y poniendolo en el "value" y no funcionó (lo puse como variable, como componente, lo exporté desde otro archivo y tampoco)

Espero que mi duda se entienda.

Saludos y muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías poner tu código en forma de texto por favor? Puedes hacerlo editando la pregunta (el botón editar se encuentra abajo de la pregunta y las etiquetas) 
y pegando el código en la pregunta. Para darle formato, puedes seleccionar todo el código y presionar las {} que están arriba de la caja de texto.
En el siguiente link se explica la importancia de NO poner capturas de código en una pregunta: 
https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-c%c3%b3digo-vale-m%c3%a1s-que-mil-im%c3%a1genes-c%c3%b3mo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu/4902#4902

Comment: Corregido. Muchas gracias por la corrección, es cierto, soy nuevo en ésto. Muy amable

Comment: Comparte lo que has intentado, saludos